# How to put todays date and time in excell cell

Tags: excel, vba

Within an Excel cell, I want to have the current (dynamic) date time printed.

I tried with following format:

```
TEXT(TODAY(); "ddmm");TEXT(TIME(HOUR(NOW());MINUTE(NOW());SECOND(NOW()));"mmss")
```

The format cell is not formatted as text. However, when I select the cell I have exactly that what is typed iso 07111533

I tried already with `TEXT(TODAY(); "ddmm")` and then my cell is filled with 0711, which is ok.

Expected result should be something like 07113815

Actual result:

```
TEXT(TODAY(); "ddmm");TEXT(TIME(HOUR(NOW());MINUTE(NOW());SECOND(NOW()));"mmss")
```

Comment: FYI that value calculated by the formula will change everytime the worksheet is opened or anytime something on the worksheet changes.  If you need that value to stop changing you will need to either use VBA, or copy and paste value at the point where you want that value to stop changing.

Answer (score 3):

You're over-complicating:

```
=TEXT(NOW(),"ddmm") & TEXT(NOW(),"mmss")
```

[image]

Comment: Is printed as 0746hh45 Almost there, I'll guess 07 is day the 46 is minutes, hh hours that are not printed and 45 the seconds. I expected 07 for days 11 for month 46 for minutes and eg 45 for seconds

Comment: What is the exact formula you're using?

Comment: TEXT(TODAY(); "ddmm");TEXT(TIME(HOUR(NOW());MINUTE(NOW());SECOND(NOW()));"mmss")

Comment: Did you try the formula I proposed, changing the `,` to `;` as needed? What is the *revised* formula you're using?